# How to customize methods in Collapseclick Library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, customization

I am using Collapseclick library for Acccordian functionality. I am facing issue if trying to call `-(UIView *)viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex:(int)index;` method and replacing switch case with for loop. I am new to objectiveC. Please help me out!

Comment: It sounds like you want to alter the method. You can copy and paste the code from the viewForCollapse... method into your own code and change it how you want, then use that method. Will this work? Otherwise, I'd have to know more about how the library code is formatted and what you are trying to do to help you out

Comment: -(UIView *)viewForCollapseClickContentViewAtIndex:(int)index {
   
     switch (index) {
        case 0:
           
            return detailloan_view;
            break;
        case 1:
            return detailoverview_view;
           
       
            
           
    }
}

Here is my viewcontroller code,where I have tried to customize the method.Problem is that I want to replace switch case with for loop here inside this method,please suggest!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it is hard to recommend you a solution without knowing how the library code is set up, but you can try subclassing whatever class implements that method. If that method is on a certain class, make another class that is a subclass of that class and override that method. Expose whatever variables you need to, if they are not already exposed in that library.

See this documentation for more instruction on subclassing:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html